# Set badge value on an UITabBar item in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, push-notification, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7, uitabbar

How can I set a badge value on an UITabBar item in AppDelegate. Inside a ViewController I write this to set the badge value on an item:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = String(noti_count)
```

But I do not know how to access an item in AppDelegate. I want to set the badge value on the index 3 when I open the app after exit it with home button, which should be inside this method:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the name of your controller is ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // do whatever you want
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(ViewController.applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)),
            name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification,
            object: nil)
    }
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("∙ \(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)) -  applicationWillEnterForeground ")
        // do whatever you want
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = String(noti_count)
    }
}
```